# Плывет верстка в Safari/iOS

Tags: ios, mac, safari

Ребят, купил шаблон, изначально тестировал на десктопе/андроиде и косяка не видел. В iphone же, и на маках верстка оказалась в хлам. Знания кой-какие имеются, но что-то не могу найти решение. Гляньте на [сайт](http://stroirost-ural.ru/)
в чем проблема? Ведь мобильная верстка есть, но в продуктах Apple она игнорируется. Разрабы шаблона молчат как рыбы...(

Comment: Кто ставит минус - это не реклама, а реальная проблема, на тостере вот хоть как то пытаются помочь, а вы...

Answer (score 2):

Вобщем, вопрос решил сам, пришло озарение :) Но большое спасибо sergski  за отклик и указание направления, покопаться в валидаторе. пока копался и нашел баг. Суть в том, что в шаблоне была анимированная предзагрузка, так вот она была убрана, но часть кода осталась. И сафари как Хатико, ждал, ждал когда пройдет предзагрузка, игнорируя все стили :) Уфф... Камень с плеч!
Спасибо за минусы, Интернет!Вы как всегда в своем репертуаре! :)

Comment: не за что! :) :)